# After CartThrob install, everything under ecommerce tab leads to account not found error

Tags: cartthrob, multi-site-manager

It's a EE multi-site, and I suspect that has something to do with the error, but not sure. I have 'msm_show_all' set to true in the config file. This is the error I get when any CartThrob link is clicked in the admin area:

"The account you are attempting to access does not exist."

But under add-ons -> modules it says it is installed successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest CT version? I know that there was a lot of extra work in there for MSM specifically.